# Want to reverse AC Motor direction - need help

Tags: reverse-polarity

I have this old Westinghouse motor it turns clockwise and I need counter clockwise. It has 3 leads at a junction on the rear, 2 line and 1 middle lead labeled 0.

[image]

Anyone know how to help?
It is a 110v 3/4 hp single phase motor model 89z123a.

Comment: Have you looked for technical documentation on this?

Comment: Could you just change the polarity of the voltage source?

Comment: @HelenaWells - changing the polarity of an AC source would have no effect.

Comment: Can you take a better picture that clearly shows which wires are the incoming AC Mains and which wires come from inside the motor?  You may have to move some wires up so that it is clear where they go.

Comment: @DwayneReid  looks like the power cable wires have lugs crimped on the ends

Comment: How is the motor constructed? Does it have a shaded pole, or is there a capacitor used to provide a phase shift to one of the coils?

Comment: If it's synchronous, then look for the startup mechanism.  If it's inductive, you'll probably have to turn the coils 180 degrees, if possible.

Comment: Does it have a run capacitor, or a start cap and a centrifugal switch? (Can you hear the switch click when the motor stops?)

Comment: If forced to guess I'd move the withe wire with the fork lug to the middle terminal.